# Recursion method that returns number of digits for a given integer

Tags: java, recursion, digits

Need to write a method that returns the number of digits foe an integer number.

At first I did it using the iterative approach and everything worked just fine, however, when I want to edit the code using recursion I'm always stuck at the first counting and can't figure out why.
Any help is much appreciated..

```
public static int numberLength(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      n *= (-1);
    } else if (n == 0) {
      return 1;
    }

    int digits = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
      digits += 1;
      numberLength(n / 10);
    }
    return digits;
```

Comment: "`if(n==0){return 1;}`" why ? if n=0 it means there's no more digit so return 0, no ?

Comment: From my perspective if the user typed 0, it's 1 digit

Comment: My problem is that the output is always 1

Comment: @vin How many digits does it take to represent 0?

Comment: With n=4 (for example) your code will return 2 digits. Because n>0 you count 1 digit, then do a substep with n/10 (5/10=0). It will enter the condition n==0, and add 1 to digit. Then the final return will be 2

Answer (score 2):

In a recursive method you need to return some value based on reducing the size of the input value and combining this with your current count so far e.g.

```
public static int numberLength(int n){ 
   if(n < 10){ 
     return 1; 
   } 

   return 1 + (numberLength(n/10)); //This line combines the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're discarding the result of `numberLength(n / 10);`

You probably meant to type:

```
int digits = 0;
if (n > 0) {
  return 1 + numberLength(n / 10);
}
return digits;
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could look like this:

```
    public static int numberLength(int n){

    if(n < 0){
        return numberLength(-n);
    }

    else if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1 + numberLength(n/10);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(numberLength(-152555)); //returns 6
}
```